# Using onOptionsItemSelected to go up from PreferenceActivity with PreferenceFragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having trouble using `onOptionsItemSelected` with Android Studio's default "Settings Activity" (which `extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity`). The important parts of the activity are:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        // [...]

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // two more fragments
}
```

This works great for the fragments -- the `onOptionsItemSelected` `@Override`s work well, returning to `SettingsActivity`, **but I want `SettingsActivity` to return control to its parent activity when the up button is used.**

I've read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and I understand that

> Although your fragment receives an on-item-selected callback for each menu item it adds, the activity is first to receive the respective callback when the user selects a menu item.

This means I can't simply add a similar `@Override` (with a different `Intent`) to `SettingsActivity` itself to handle the case I want to, lest the fragments return to the parent activity instead.

I've attempted handling this via `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".BlahBlahActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.appthing.BlahBlahActivity" />
</activity>
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything at all.

What's a good way, if any, to deal with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the template created by Android Studio onOptionsItemSelected methods belong to the fragments.

I solved by commenting them and writing onOptionsItemSelected method for the activity overriding onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with a generated PreferenceActivitiy from Android Studio. However, I currently only have one level of depth in my preferences but I plan to have at least 2 so I cant tell right now if it will still work then. I guess it shoul

Answer (score 1):

After several unfruitful hours of searching the web, I came up with a crude (but slightly hackish) solution of my own.

I added a field to `SettingsActivity`: `private boolean inFragment;`

In the fragments' `onCreate()` methods, I then added

```
((SettingsActivity) getActivity()).inFragment = true;
```

Finally, I then used this `@Override` in `SettingsActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (!inFragment) {
            Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This will work for my purposes, but I feel like there is probably (or should be) a better way.