# Settings Activity how to navigate back using the arrow at the top

Tags: java, android-studio, button, android-activity, settings

Hi I've created a settings Activity and when I am in the settings menu and press the back button of the phone i get directed to the "home screen" which is correct but when I am pressing the top arrow of the settings menu nothings happends, it seems to be just a button. Please see imgur to see which arrow i mean. [Back arrow in the settings activity, press here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lANSf.jpg) I've looked around in the java code and seems to have found the button? All help is *app*reciated!!

Here is the whole java file of the settings menu.

```js
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
                // using RingtoneManager.
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                    // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                    preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

                } else {
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                            preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                    if (ringtone == null) {
                        // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                        preference.setSummary(null);
                    } else {
                        // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                        // name.
                        String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                        preference.setSummary(name);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                // simple string representation.
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };


    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    /**
     * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
     * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
     * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
     * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
     * dependent on the type of preference.
     *
     * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
     */
    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));




        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    }
```

I think this is the button?

```js
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You need to define parent `Activity` for your `SettingsActivity` using:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
  android:value=".MainActivity"/>
```

then in your class:

```
 /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

if you're using already AppCompatActivity with `Toolbar`, check this solution:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

// add back arrow to toolbar
if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

If you're also want to handle this event or change the backButton icon, go to: [Display Back Arrow on Toolbar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar-android)

**Edit:** add to your activity class this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: 
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Hi i added the data into androidmanifest (see edited question). and i changed actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); . But sorry when i press the arrow the only thing the log cat show is still, action_down and action_up (normal button press). nothing more :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tim I suppose taht problem still happens. I edited my ansdwer

Comment: Haha thank you for all your help, i also found the answer! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540497/using-onoptionsitemselected-to-go-up-from-preferenceactivity-with-preferencefrag i read this link. I tried google with the whooole code. Even though I always search the web before I ask. Thank you for taking your time looking all this up. I appreciate it. I will vote you up! Have a good night! :D

Answer (score 3):

In your AndroidManifest.xml , add this in the Activity tag

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".HomeScreenActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining the answers above

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainSettingsFragment()).commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_settings">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should try it.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)`enter code here`
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: In Your  SettingActivity's  onOptionsItemSelected() ----> startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));  this line is creating problem for you.